# Connection error for sqlserver rake db:migrate

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error:

```
Open
OLE error code:80004005 in Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
HRESULT error code:0×80020009
Exception occurred.
```

I have tried following the directions [here](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoConnectToMicrosoftSQLServer) with no luck.

Any ideas?

***FIXED***

My specific issue I believe was related to having to many mixed systems installed on my laptop. I had Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 components and SQL Server Management Standard loaded with SQL Server Express Edition as well as various other components that might have affected the stability of my environment. Once I reloaded Vista and went back through the steps [from the link above](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoConnectToMicrosoftSQLServer) it worked without issue.

I only loaded the Express Editions of SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?
Could you post your database.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My specifc issue I believe was related to having to many mixed systems installed on my laptop. I had Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 componets and SQL Server Managment Standard loaded with SQL Server Express Edition as well as various other componets that might have effected the stability of my envirnomnet. Once I reloaded Vista and went back through the steps on http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoConnectToMicrosoftSQLServer it worked without issue.

I only loaded the Express Editions of SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

Usually a authentication/permissions error.

Is the SQL Server on the same box as the web server, review the accounts they are running under, and review the type of connection you are making (integrated or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

Random guess: By default SQL Server (express, at least anyway) does NOT enable network access. The SQL Admin manager tools connect to it using named pipes, however rails most likely will be trying to use TCP.